# databricks, spark, scala, cannot use lag() on long

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a data file named q6 that looks like this:

```
date,count
2019-01-07,9553
2019-01-08,9930
2019-01-28,10160
2019-01-30,9881
2019-01-26,10867
2019-02-01,8
2019-01-20,6823
2019-01-22,9796
2019-01-19,9295
2019-01-05,9432
2019-01-03,10063
2018-12-31,13
2019-01-31,9804
2019-01-10,11051
2019-01-17,11268
2019-01-04,10451
```

I want to calculate the difference between each date and the previous date, and the percent increase/decrease. Here is the schema of my file:

```
root
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Here are the commands I have tried (some of them, anyway):

```
q6 = q6.groupBy("date").count()
//q6 = q6.withColumn("count", $"count" as "Int")//col("count").cast("int")
//q6 = q6.sort("date")
//q6.printSchema()
val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy("date")
q6 = q6.withColumn("lag", lag("count",1).over(windowSpec))
//q6 = q6.withColumn("prev_value", lag(q6.count).over(windowSpec))
//q6 = q6.withColumn("diff", when(isnull(q6.count - q6.prev_value), 0).otherwise(q6.price - q6.prev_value))
display(q6)
```

This runs without error, but I get nulls, like this:

```
date,count,lag
2019-01-07,9553,null
2019-01-08,9930,null
2019-01-28,10160,null
2019-01-30,9881,null
2019-01-26,10867,null
2019-02-01,8,null
2019-01-20,6823,null
2019-01-22,9796,null
2019-01-19,9295,null
2019-01-05,9432,null
2019-01-03,10063,null
2018-12-31,13,null
```

I use SQL Server and window functions, and while I am not especially proficient with them, I can mostly get them to work without too much of a problem. I threw my dataset into SQL Server and everything worked! What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you'd write it as

```
lag(count) over (order by date)
```

So in Scala Spark, you'd write

```
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("date")
q6 = q6.withColumn("lag", lag("count", 1).over(windowSpec))
```

If you partitioned by date, since each date only has 1 associated row, `lag` will result in null. There is no need to partition by date.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I partitioned the window spec. Here is what I should have done:

```
val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("date")
```

Notice that the partitionBy() function does not take a parameter. It works perfectly now.

As an aside, I'm struggling with this, but being able to implement a solution in SQL Server is very helpful. Our problem is that we have outgrown our database and need to perform analysis on very large amounts of data. Took me years to learn SQL Server. Guess it will take me years to learn Spark --- but it will most definitely be worth it!

Comment: Note that spark will shuffle each partition onto a single executor (so if your data became enormous this might be a problem)